# Ending a Program Mid-Run

Tags: python, exit, message-pump, pythoncom

**pythoncom.PumpMessages()**

From what I understand this line basically tells the program to wait forever. For my purposes it seems to be working. However, I'd like to be able to end the program given the right stimulus. How would one go about ending the above line, or stopping the program from running any further.

Comment: No answer will be full until you'd specify *what* stimulus exactly are you waiting for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to these [docs](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/pythoncom.html), `pythoncom.PumpMessages()`:

> > Pumps all messages for the current thread until a WM_QUIT message.

So one way to stop collecting messages is by posting a WM_QUIT message to the message queue by using the [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html) library to call [PostQuitMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644945%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
ctypes.windll.user32.PostQuitMessage(0)
```

Comment: 8 years later, this does not seem to work anymore :)

Answer (score 7):

Here's an example of quitting the app using a timer thread:

```
import win32api
import win32con
import pythoncom
from threading import Timer

main_thread_id = win32api.GetCurrentThreadId()

def on_timer():
    win32api.PostThreadMessage(main_thread_id, win32con.WM_QUIT, 0, 0);

t = Timer(5.0, on_timer) # Quit after 5 seconds
t.start()

pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

`PostQuitMessage()` will work only from the main thread, but then again the main thread *is blocked*, so it's not very useful by itself. You can only use it if you hook your own custom message handling into the message loop.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to extend both answers by [Gregg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6023566/2617691) and [Boaz Yaniv](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6023713/2617691). You would normally run blocking code in separate thread therefore you need to send WM_QUIT to the thread. You should use [PostQuitMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644945(v=vs.85).aspx) as noted by Gregg but that works only in current thread. You shouldn't use [PostThreadMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644946(v=vs.85).aspx) to send WM_QUIT (can't remember where I see it in docs). You can read more about it in discussion "[Why is there a special PostQuitMessage function?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20051104-33/?p=33453)". I think it's better to send WM_CLOSE to the thread first.

```
# if more hotkeys needs to be supported at the same time this class needs to be rewritten
class HotKey:
    def __init__(self, modifier_key, virtual_key, callback):
        self.hotkey_id = 1
        # shared variable to pass thread id
        self.pid = mpdummy.Value('l', 0)

        # start checking hotkey press in new thread
        self.process_pool = mpdummy.Pool()
        self.process_pool.apply_async(HotKey.register, (self.hotkey_id, self.pid, modifier_key, virtual_key, callback, ))
        self.process_pool.close()

    # bind windows global hotkey
    @staticmethod
    def register(hotkey_id, pid, modifier_key, virtual_key, callback):
        # set thread ID to shared variable
        # Win API could also be used:
        # ctypes.windll.Kernel32.GetCurrentThreadId()
        pid.value = mpdummy.current_process().ident

        # register hotkey with Win API
        logging.getLogger('default').info("Registering hotkey with id " + str(hotkey_id) + " for key " + str(modifier_key) + " " + str(virtual_key))
        if not ctypes.windll.user32.RegisterHotKey(None, hotkey_id, modifier_key, virtual_key):
            logging.getLogger('default').info("Unable to register hotkey with id " + str(hotkey_id))

        msg = ctypes.wintypes.MSG()
        try:
            # wait for a message - it doesn't return until some message arrives
            while ctypes.windll.user32.GetMessageA(ctypes.byref(msg), None, 0, 0) != 0:
                # WM_HOTKEY     0x0312
                # https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646279(v=vs.85).aspx
                if msg.message == 0x0312:
                    logging.getLogger('default').info("Pressed hotkey with id " + str(hotkey_id))
                    callback()
                # WM_CLOSE
                # https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632617(v=vs.85).aspx
                elif msg.message == 0x0010:
                    # quit current thread
                    # WM_QUIT shouldn't be send with PostThreadMessageA therefore we send WM_CLOSE and quit inside thread.
                    # More info at:
                    # https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644945(v=vs.85).aspx
                    # https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20051104-33/?p=33453
                    ctypes.windll.user32.PostQuitMessage(0)
                ctypes.windll.user32.TranslateMessage(ctypes.byref(msg))
                ctypes.windll.user32.DispatchMessageA(ctypes.byref(msg))
        finally:
            logging.getLogger('default').info("Unregistering hotkey for id " + str(hotkey_id))
            ctypes.windll.user32.UnregisterHotKey(None, hotkey_id)

    def unregister(self):
        # send WM_CLOSE signal to thread checking for messages
        # WM_CLOSE      0x0010
        # https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632617(v=vs.85).aspx
        ctypes.windll.user32.PostThreadMessageA(self.pid.value, 0x0010, 0, 0)
        # wait for thread to finish
        self.process_pool.join()
```

I am using it for RegisterHotKey but principle is same. This class could be called as:

```
# bind global hotkey for "pressing" start/split button
# MOD_ALT       0x0001
# VK_F12        0x7B
# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309(v=vs.85).aspx
# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731.aspx
self.hotkey = hotkey.HotKey(0x0001, 0x7B, self.special_key_pressed)
```

When you want to end waiting for messages call:

```
self.hotkey.unregister()
```