# How do I use my own loop with pyhook instead of pumpMessages()?

Tags: python, pyhook

I'm trying to use pyhooks to detect mouse clicks anywhere on screen. The problem is that I can only get it to work with PumpMessages(). I'd like it operate inside of a while loop that I've constructed. Is there a way to accomplish this/why does it need pumpMessages?

```
def onclick(event):
    print 'Mouse click!'
    return True


hm = pyHook.HookManager()

hm.MouseLeftDown = onclick

hm.HookMouse()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
hm.UnhookMouse()
```

The above is the only way I can get it to run.

I'm trying to accomplish something like this:

```
sTime = time.time()

def onclick(event):
    global sTime
    print 'Time between clicks equals: %i' % time.time() - stime
    sTime = time.time()
    return True

hm.MouseLeftDown = OnClick

while True:

    hm.HookMouse()
```

**EDIT:** I am not a smart man. There is no need for a while loop in the scenario..

Sigh..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From the pyhook tutorial](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/pyhook/index.php?title=PyHook_Tutorial#Message_Pump):

> Any application that wishes to receive notifications of global input
>   events must have a Windows message pump.

However, this shouldn't necessarily prevent your code from working.  Why don't you post what you are trying to do, and we can look for a way to use the message pump in the context of your code.

One way you might be able to solve your problem is through PostQuitMessages(original solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023172/ending-a-program-mid-run))

```
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.user32.PostQuitMessage(0)
```

Answer (score 16):

Just for future reference, you can use `pythoncom.PumpWaitingMessages()` inside the while loop, since it does not lock the execution. Something like this:

```
while True:
    # your code here
    pythoncom.PumpWaitingMessages()
```

Comment: Agree with Muppet. This should be the correct answer. Thanks for this I searched quite a while before finding this simple solution,

Comment: but isn't that hogging the CPU since it's non-blocking?

Comment: It depends on what your code is doing. In my code, for instance, I needed to check many things before pumping messages, so I couldn't be blocked in the `PostQuitMessage` call.