# How to terminate the running function in Python Shell?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I thought this is an easy task but I googled around and had no clue at all.
I'm trying to run the pyhook tutorial and once I get to pythoncom.PumpMessages(), the function will stay idle and wait for Windows events.

I don't want to close down the window nor restart the shell because of all imported library and defined functions. Is there any way to termindate just the function?

I tried ctrl+c but it doesn't work at all.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sometimes, ctrl+break works better.

Comment: @martineau I tried that, and that didn't work either. Is there any configuration or something? I know a lot of people have no problem using ctrl+c or ctrl+break.

Comment: Take at look at the answer to [Ending a Program Mid-Run](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023172/ending-a-program-mid-run).