# How to open another program upon exiting the program in Python?

Tags: python, windows

I have a program that requires some cleaning up after exiting, and have written a seperate .py file for this. However, the program I use stays in an infinite loop at one part:

```
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

Because of this, there is no "natural" closing of the program. The only way is to end the process from task manager.

So I ask: is there a way to, upon being ended from task manager, to run my clean up python script automatically?

**Edit:** I could put it in an infinite loop in a different way, such as this, if it helps:

```
while True:
    pythoncom.PumpWaitingMessages()
```

Comment: check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023172/ending-a-program-mid-run

Answer (score 3):

There is sample from my project:

```
import signal

def term(*args,**kwargs):
    sys.stderr.write('\nStopping...')
    do_cleaning_stuff_here()

signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, term)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, term)
signal.signal(signal.SIGQUIT, term)
yuor_main_code_here()
```

With infinite loop:

```
import signal

def term(*args,**kwargs):
    global running
    sys.stderr.write('\nStopping...')
    running=False

signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, term)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, term)
signal.signal(signal.SIGQUIT, term)
running=True
while running:
    handle()
cleanup()
```

windows signals translated to unix equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

You can run both scripts from a separate python script and kill the first process before running the second.

For example using subprocess.Popen:

```
 proc1 = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell = True)
 time.sleep(waititme) #or other flag, such as reading another source
 proc1.kill() 
 proc2 = subprocess.Popen(cmd2, shell = True)
```

Answer (score 1):

In unix, when you kill a process, you send it a signal. For example, CTRL-C causes a signal sent to the program.

On windows, some of these signals are emulated, including CTRL-C. If your loop isn't calling functions that block the CTRL-C signal, then you can press CTRL-C to kill the loop. Could you try terminating your program with CTRL-C instead of doing it through the task manager?

If it works that way, you can write a handler to catch the CTRL-C signal, cleanup the program state, and `sys.exit()`.

Here is code to capture the signal:
[How do I capture SIGINT in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112343/how-do-i-capture-sigint-in-python)

Comment: CTRL-C sends SIGINT to python script

Comment: @eri, Yes, and there is a link to "How do I capture SIGINT in Python."